# Kinect SDK 2.0 handle and acquire depth frame

Tags: c++, kinect, handle

I am actually working with the Kinect V2 (the one for Xbox One) and I am trying to have a depth stream. I want to see what the depth sensor of Kinect sees. But I don't succeed to open a stream. I only succeed to open a single frame with another piece of code, but not a video. With a few research, I have tried to use handles, but the code I wrote don't printe on the screen the line 'stream' put at the end of the code. I am working on VS2012, the code is in C++.

I think I have this because I don't know how to use correcty an handle... If anybody could help me and explain to me what an handle is instead of a kind of pointer to something, it would be great. Thank you

Here is my code :

`HRESULT hr=S_OK;
    WAITABLE_HANDLE *stream=nullptr;
    IKinectSensor* kinectSensor=nullptr;`

```
if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    std::cout << "Success IKinectSensor::GetDefaultSensor" << std::endl;
}

else
{
    std::cout << "Failed IKinectSensor::GetDefaultSensor" << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Opening sensors" << std::endl;
if(kinectSensor != NULL)
{
    hr = kinectSensor->Open();

    Sleep(sleeptime*5);
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Success IKinectSensor::Open" << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed IKinectSensor::Open" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

}

```
hr = kinectSensor->OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(FrameSourceTypes_Depth | FrameSourceTypes_Color , &multiSourceReader);
if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    std::cout << "reader open" << std::endl;

    hr = multiSourceReader->SubscribeMultiSourceFrameArrived(stream);
    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        std::cout << "stream" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please! I really need help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use a handle. See the below code snippet for getting the depth frame from a multisource frame reader and display it with OpenCV.

```
#include <Kinect.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

// helper function
template <class Interface> inline void safe_release(Interface **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

bool setup_kinect_sensor_and_acquire_frame()
{
    IKinectSensor* kinect_sensor

    // initialize kinect sensor
    HRESULT hr = GetDefaultKinectSensor(&kinect_sensor);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !kinect_sensor)
    {
        safe_release(&p_multisource_frame);
        return false;
    }

    kinect_sensor->Open();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // initialize kinect multisource frame reader
    IMultiSourceFrameReader* kinect_multisource_reader;
    hr = kinect_sensor->OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(FrameSourceTypes_Depth, &kinect_multisource_reader;);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        safe_release(&kinect_multisource_reader);
        return false;
    }

    // acquire multisource frame
    IMultiSourceFrame* p_multisource_frame = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = kinect_multisource_reader->AcquireLatestFrame(&p_multisource_frame);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        safe_release(&p_multisource_frame);
        return false;
    }

    // get depth frame
    IDepthFrameReference* p_depth_frame_ref = NULL;
    hr = p_multisource_frame->get_DepthFrameReference(&p_depth_frame_ref);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        safe_release(&p_depth_frame_ref);
        return false;
    }

    IDepthFrame* p_depth_frame = NULL;
    IFrameDescription* p_frame_description = NULL;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    unsigned short depth_min_distance = 0;
    unsigned short depth_max_distance = 0;
    unsigned short* p_depth_buffer = NULL;

    hr = p_depth_frame_ref->AcquireFrame(&p_depth_frame);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = p_depth_frame->get_FrameDescription(&p_frame_description);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = p_frame_description->get_Width(&width);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = p_frame_description->get_Height(&height);
    }
    if (width != 512 || height != 424)
    {
        safe_release(&p_depth_frame);
        safe_release(&p_frame_description);
        return false;
    }

    // process depth frame
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = p_depth_frame->get_DepthMinReliableDistance(&depth_min_distance);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = p_depth_frame->get_DepthMaxReliableDistance(&depth_max_distance);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {   
        int size = 512 * 424;
        p_depth_buffer = new unsigned short[size];
        hr = p_depth_frame->CopyFrameDataToArray(size, p_depth_buffer);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            cv::Mat depth_map(cv::Size(DEPTH_WIDTH, DEPTH_HEIGHT), CV_16UC1, p_depth_buffer);
            double scale = 255.0 / (depth_max_distance - depth_min_distance);
            depth_map.convertTo(depth_frame, CV_8UC1, scale);
            cv::imshow("depth", depth_map);
        }
    }

    // Clean up depth frame
    safe_release(&p_depth_frame_ref);
    safe_release(&p_depth_frame);
    safe_release(&p_frame_description);
    if (p_depth_buffer != NULL) {
        delete[] p_depth_buffer;
        p_depth_buffer = NULL;
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```